# How to update source code without rebuilding image

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I created a new repository on GitLab where I built a docker image for my angular project.
Now I made some changes in the source code locally.
Is there a way I can update the docker image without rebuilding it?

Comment: This is a deficiency of a naive Docker project. Your choices are generally: 1) Rebuild the image each time to run. Put your ADD towards the end, so the previous steps can be cached. Or 2) mount your code into a base image during development.